# How to replace a subtree with some other tree?

Tags: scala, macros, abstract-syntax-tree, scala-macros

In Scala macro, I want to do something like this:

I have a `Tree` (possibly large). Now I want to find a subtree of this tree that has some concrete form, e.g. `Apply(_, _)`. And now I want to create a new tree that is a copy of the original tree, but the found subtree is replaced by some other tree.

With something like this, I could for example replace invocation of some method with invocation of some other method.

Is something like this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm very interested in seeing alternative approaches to tree transformation, however, they have yet to arrive (and we actually have an ongoing investigation in this direction).

To get things done in the meanwhile, you can extend `Transformer`, override its `transform` method and then pattern match against the concrete form of trees you're interested in. Call `super.transform` to recursively replace in subtrees.

Comment: Thanks, I saw the `Transformer`, but the word `internal` in package name scared me away.

Comment: The implementation is internal, yes, but the interface is public: https://github.com/scalamacros/kepler/blob/18a906bb9a6c6b50d286ca76f219a5b351514ae4/src/reflect/scala/reflect/api/Trees.scala#L2897.

Comment: @EugeneBurmako anything new in this regard since then? I don't see how I can find and _replace_ a subtree of a tree.

Comment: OK, I [figured out](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.12.2/src/reflect/scala/reflect/internal/Trees.scala#L1340) that calling `super.transform` recursively traverses the tree. Didn't see it documented anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

Is it possible??? Definitively **Yes**!

The general concept is that of "persistent data structures." Those that "persist" as much as possible of the original value in the new variant.

When it comes to trees, the "Zipper" concept is applicable. It lets you navigate into a graph structure while maintaining a data structure that allows the reconstruction of a new value that shares maximally with the original modulo the changes you've applied to create the new variant.

Check it out. Many references can be found, as well as implementations, including ScalaZ.