# Modifying a node in a Scala AST

Tags: scala, reflection, scala-2.10

I understand that it is possible to obtain a Tree corresponding to a Scala expression, and also to traverse the resulting tree. Suppose that a given tree node matches some criterion, what method calls do I need to be able to modify it in place?, i.e. replace it with some other Tree?

```
object traverser extends Traverser {
    var applies = List[Apply]()

    override def traverse(tree: Tree): Unit = tree match {
        case someCriterion => modifyNodeSomehow // How to do this?
        // Otherwise...
        case app @ Apply(fun, args) =>
            applies = app :: applies
            super.traverse(fun)
            super.traverseTrees(args)
        case _ => super.traverse(tree)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14466124/how-to-replace-a-subtree-with-some-other-tree) I was suggested to use [Transformer](https://github.com/scalamacros/kepler/blob/18a906bb9a6c6b50d286ca76f219a5b351514ae4/src/reflect/scala/reflect/api/Trees.scala#L2897) to do something similar. AFAIK it is not possible to modify the tree in place, however.

Comment: Thanks - Transformer exactly does what is required (albeit not inplace, but in a functional style).